# Column concatenation in Order by expression. Is it wrong?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What are pros and cons whether I use Order by expression like this:

```
select * from table1
order by column1 || column2 || column3 || column4
```

or in this way:

```
select * from table1
order by column1, column2, column3, column4
```

How each one does impact on performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concatenation is unnecessary and may produce incorrect results.  For instance, consider these values:

```
abc       a     b     c
ab        d     e     f
```

The concatenation will put the first row first.  By individual keys, it will put the second one first.

It can slow down the `order by`, if the `order by` can make use of indexes.